# Lot of noise in webrtc audio/video

Tags: webrtc

I have developed a video chat app with webrtc api. I have fallowed the steps given by webrtc. Video working fine. But there is a lot of noice from my laptop. sound is not clear.

But in google developed demo site https://apprtc.appspot.com/ works with out any noise(better compare with us).

I fallowed the same procedure what they did. But no luck.

But in headset this echo is not hearing. This happens when we haering the sound from laptop without headset.

Please give me some suggestion on this.

Thanks in advance. Looking foward for the response.

Comment: Is there any echo cancellation mechanism in webrtc.

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at this demo [webrtc conferencing](http://tokbox.com/opentok/webrtc/demo) supports four callers. This link describes the implentation details [architecture](http://tokbox.com/opentok/docs/concepts/architecture.html)

Comment: Thanks Hanu. Video is working fine. But audio getting with lot of noise.  After some googling i understood that we eneed to cancel the echo. https://sites.google.com/site/webrtc/blog/webrtcimprovementoptimizedaecacousticechocancellation                                                                       How to implement this in webrtc. Any idea ?